# Migrate annotation processor to androidX

Tags: android, androidx, annotation-processor

I've a annotation processor for android with following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0'
compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
```

In my processor I access `Activity` and `Fragment` class. Which includes do I need now to be able to use the new android x `Fragment`? I can't find anything about this...

I naivly tried adding

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
// or
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

But this does not help...

Answer (score 0):

On the new AndroidX projects, `Fragment`s import are like this:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

Which means, you should already have added the dependencies and migrated to AndroidX which will show the dependenices like following for example:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

So, you won't probably need this:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I tried `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0` but this is not working in my java project. In my android projects I use this, but their should be some minimal libraries that only declare the classes for the use in annotation processors...

Comment: Didn't you use Migrate to Androidx by Android Studio? Or you just added the dependencies by your own? As you know, we weren't used to use another dependency for the `Fragment`s before and now, it's like the same situation.